# ; expected in export default

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code:

```
export default () => {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    authenticating: false
  }

  renderCurrentState() {
     if (this.state.authenticating) {
        return (
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        )
     }

     return (
       <View>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/Octocat.png")} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.formContainer}>
      <LoginForm />
    </View>
    </View>
     )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       {this.renderCurrentState}
    </View>
  );
};
```

On `renderCurrentState() {` the curly bracket is pinged as error with the message:
`';' expected`. I am barely stepping in react/react-native so I probably doing something in worn way. `export default () => {...}` is what I saw from a tutorial. Not sure if it has to be a `class` with a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
const renderCurrentState = () => {
     if (this.state.authenticating) {
        return (
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        )
     }
```

Comment: Working :). Thank you .

Comment: Glad to help @TomaTomov. :)